# Jumbotron and Navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out how I can have the my navigation sit ontop of the jumobtron but still be constrained to have the container class. Also my h1 and I'm wanting to have my h1 and p inside my header to be inside the container as well but I want the jumbotron to be full across the width of the page. I do not have any styles of my own it is all from bootstrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Me - Web Designer/Developer</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
       <![endif]-->
    </head>
   <body>

       <header class="jumbotron">

           <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
          </nav>

          <h1>Me</h1><p class="lead">Web Developer</p>
        </header>

        <div class="container">

            <section id="services">
                <h2 class="text-center">Services</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    ....
```

Comment: This is fairly unclear what you are after.  Can you please break it down - it sounds like you have multiple things you want help with, but there's not a very good "problem" statement, and there's nothing on what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example. Change your navbar to `background: transparent`, place a `container` inside the `jumbotron` and inside the `navbar` as well.

```
<header class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
```

**Working Example:**

```css
nav.navbar {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  nav.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
header {
  background-image: url('http://www.100resilientcities.org/page/-/100rc/img/cities/cities-la_optimized.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 400px;
}
header.jumbotron h1 {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
header.jumbotron h1,
header.jumbotron p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#works">Works</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>

    <h1>Me</h1>
    <p class="lead">Web Developer</p>

  </div>
</header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jumbotron and Navbars are different things and shouldn't be put one inside the other. When you define the nav class to be **navbar-fixed-top**, your navigation is taken away from the normal flow of the page, so you'd want something like this:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <header class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Me</h1>
            <p class="lead">Web Developer</p>
        </div>
    </header>
```

I believe this should be enough for your needs. Please do tell if it's not.

Comment: Well thank you for your help however I'm wondering how I can have the jumbotron have the nav sit on top of it so that the text can be seen through the jumbotron because I'm going to put an image to use inside of there.